# Objective-C Design Help Needed, Need Protocol Possibly?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, protocols

I have a situation where ClassA contains a `UIView` property. I have two children of ClassA, ChildA and ChildB, both set this `UIView` property for themselves with two different types of `UIView` subclasses. I'd like to require that both of these `UIView` subclasses have a property called maximumDimension, and then I'd like to be able to set it in ClassA using its own `UIView` property.

What is the best way to accomplish this? Would it be a protocol? If so would someone be able to provide code on how this can be achieved in Objective-C?

Comment: What do you mean with children of ClassA? Subclass? Or is ClassA some kind of a node?

Comment: Why don't you just implement it in the superclass?  Are the UIView classes in the children so different?

Comment: @DrummerB I'd assume they're two different subclasses of UIView.

Comment: @DrummerB - yes ChildA and ChildB are subclasses

Comment: @iluvcapra - Because both of these UIView subclasses need this property available in their own classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would it be a protocol?

Yes:

```
@protocol Foo <NSObject>
@property (nonatomic, assign) int maximumDimensions; // wild guess to type from name
@end
```

Then the actual property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <Foo> bar;
```

Comment: A category would also work here: `@interface UIView (MaxDimensions) @property ( nonatomic, readonly ) CGSize maxDimensions ; @end` although it's less "orthodox".

Comment: @nielsbot That's the other way around, I believe. OP asks how it should be declared in the class that requires its property to have a particular property, and not how it may be implemented on the actual, concrete classes.

Comment: Thanks. So would I ultimately set bar to Class A's UIView property, or could bar be a UIView?

Comment: @StackOverFlowRider I don't see what you mean there.

Comment: My point was that you could provide a _maximumDimensions_ property on every _UIView_, and also provide a default implementation. Now methods of ClassA can access `self.view.maximumDimensions`. I think it's another way to solve the problem, although some might consider it "changing the question" instead :)

Comment: I understand implementing the protocol and getting the two UIView subclasses to follow it (just like a delegate <SomeClassDelegate>). However, I don't understand what is happening in Class A. I'm assuming that's where bar is declared? Can bar be a UIView?

Comment: @StackOverFlowRider It can. And you declare that property wherever you need.

Comment: If you have lots of code in subclasses _ChildA_ and _ChildB_ then H2CO3's answer makes the most sense.. My proposal, simply for discussion, might allow you to avoid subclassing in some cases... which I think is a win.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Any ideas on what to name the protocol? (and thanks for all your help).

Comment: @StackOverFlowRider It depends on what kind of use case you need it for. Could you give an example?

Comment: im using ClassA to set maximumDimension on the UIView based on it's superview. That's all.

Answer (score 2):

For discussion's sake, here's a solution that uses a category instead of a protocol, extending `UIView` to have a *maximumDimensions* property:

**UIView+MaximumDimensions.h**

```
@interface UIView (MaximumDimensions)
@property ( nonatomic, readonly ) CGSize maximumDimensions ;
@end
```

**UIView+MaximumDimensions.m**

```
@implementation UIView (MaximumDimensions)
-(CGSize)maximumDimensions { return self.bounds.size ; }
@end
```

Now, in the methods of `ClassA`, you can access `self.view.maximumDimensions`. (Because UIView now has a *maximumDimensions* property.) Your subclasses of `UIView`, `ChildA` and `ChildB` can implement `-maximumDimensions` to return the correct answer.